# Creating page rule is a must after adding a website to CloudFlare?

Tags: cloudflare

New to CloduFlare and confused with a few concept such as Page Rules.

Simply, my main aim is to make my WP blog loading faster, which is quite slow currently. I already signed up a free account at CloduFlare. My question is that creating page rule is mandatory after adding website?

What kind of additional settings I should make?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not mandatory to create a page rule. But CloudFlare doesn't cache pages (the html) by default.

Your best option is to install a wp-based cacher like Comet Cache. It's intelligent enough to know when to flush cached pages. You'll get a 10x speed boost. From there CloudFlare will speed up static resources, etc.

You can have a similar and faster html caching mechanism at CloudFlare on the free plan, but not intelligent WP caching - that's only on paid plans.